# Using rdiff in Windows

Tags: diff, rsync, cwrsync

I recently found rdiff utility : http://beerpla.net/2008/05/12/a-better-diff-or-what-to-do-when-gnu-diff-runs-out-of-memory-diff-memory-exhausted/ that find differences between 2 huge files.

How can I use it in Windows? I am using PHP file to execute diff. Is rdiff the same way?

I want to implement the steps in the above link. Can I wrote it in PHP? and from where can execute rdiff? from Windows cmd? or cygwin cmd?

Answer (score 3):

Here is another prepared windows binary for rdiff since other link in @H47 answer is not working - [rdiff-2.0.2-win64.zip](https://mega.nz/#!t8sTxAzZ!q103KBDSa1XUQ4AJvrJ2Xti1RoLhik5A_ArU7bdYBcI) (mega.nz)

Compiled from librsync-2.0.2 using msys2 mingw64 gcc compiler.

EDIT 2023: Since this answer is still getting hits, check also official github librsync repo because there are now Windows builds in releases. There are some solvable issues - more info https://github.com/librsync/librsync/issues/253#issuecomment-1456291081

Answer (score 1):

You will need to compile rdiff for Windows yourself as it's not readily available. It's not that difficult, you need to:
- download the librsync source from github.com/librsync/librsync/releases
- install Cygwin
- compile following these instructions librsync.sourcefrog.net/page_install.html
- profit :-)

If you'd like, you can use my MinGW x64 build from here - www.filedropper.com/rdiff-win-200